# NSInvalidArgumentException -[NSAttributeDictionary textContainerForAttributedString:containerSize:lineFragmentPadding:]:

Tags: ios

I am experiencing a crash on device (getting data from crashlytics) which is not one I can recreate.
Nor this time can I figure it from the crash stack.
The app is iOS7+ and crashes are happening on iOS7

**Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[NSAttributeDictionary textContainerForAttributedString:containerSize:lineFragmentPadding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x188c6820**

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2f79becb __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39f36ce7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2f79f7f7 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 202
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2f79e0f7 ___forwarding___ + 706
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2f6ed058 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5  UIFoundation                   0x3741e915 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 12252
6  UIFoundation                   0x3741b863 -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:] + 150
7  UIKit                          0x31fe62a9 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 4224
8  UIKit                          0x3204c6e9 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 500
9  UIKit                          0x3204c4eb -[UILabel drawRect:] + 78
10 UIKit                          0x3204c489 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 372
11 QuartzCore                     0x31c78189 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 100
12 QuartzCore                     0x31c61c5b CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 1858
13 QuartzCore                     0x31d3dc1d ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 52
14 QuartzCore                     0x31c6150b x_blame_allocations + 82
15 QuartzCore                     0x31c611bf CA::Layer::display_() + 1118
16 QuartzCore                     0x31c44d41 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 208
17 QuartzCore                     0x31c449d9 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
18 QuartzCore                     0x31c443e5 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 228
19 QuartzCore                     0x31c441f7 CA::Transaction::commit() + 314
20 QuartzCore                     0x31c718e3 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 162
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5516d1 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 164
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a551453 _pthread_exit + 86
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5521b9 pthread_exit + 28
24 Foundation                     0x300d9703 +[NSThread exit] + 10
25 Foundation                     0x30185a2d __NSThread__main__ + 1092
26 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a552959 _pthread_body + 140
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5528cb _pthread_start + 102
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a550ae8 thread_start + 8
```

Comment: So, do you deal with NSAttributeDictonarys or any drawing calls in any of your code?

Comment: (From searching the web it seems most likely that either you have a deallocated instance of something or you're making a call in a background thread that should be in the UI thread.)

Comment: just did a search, no use of NSAttributeDictonarys in my app.

Comment: What about any functions with "draw" in the name?

Comment: I have a few, but don't get what you are seeing that makes that relevant ? - please explain

Comment: The failure occurred during drawing.  If you somehow specified that a "draw" operation was to occur in an inappropriate situation that could be it.  Eg, scheduling a draw operation to run in background.  (In fact, what thread did the error occur in?)

Comment: looking at the crashyltics (I can't reproduce this myself) it just says thread 8 - so your correct not the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the comments, it looks like you may not be on your main thread when trying to initiate a draw function. You may have an animation or a CATransaction somewhere that's being carried out on a separate thread. If you happen to know where that may be possible within your app, I would suggest throwing it on the main thread by using

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //perform any animation or main thread drawing code here
});
```

Comment: It could well be and I know how to fix it - however the original issue remains that from the stack trace I have no idea on how to pin point the code in the question. It is also worth noting the crash reports indicate this ONLY occurs on ios7 and it's fine on ios8

Comment: Are there any places where you are applying a CATransaction to a UILabel? Or animating a UILabel?

Comment: zero CATransaction in my code base,other interesting thing is the crash only happening on ios7 - it is fine on ios8 (the app has about a 50/50 ratio on userbase) - just searching for UILabel animations

Comment: only anim on labels is alpha changes which I guess could cause this ??!?!

Comment: Do any of your labels/buttons start with newline/carriage returns in their text?